# Prevent duplicate form submission on login

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an issue that causes [OOME/Stackoverflow as per this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064622/grails-heap-space-overflowing-intermittently), almost certainly now it seems this is caused by duplicate form submissions on login.  This is all done using the Spring Security plugin. Is there a way to prevent this?

I thought of using  useToken/withForm but can't see how as Spring Security posts to j_spring_security_check so I don't have control over that.

Am using a custom UserDetailsService and can see how to check if there is a current session being logged into such as via RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.sessionMutex.session.attributes.xyz but not sure that seems correct way either.

Using Grails 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

"Grails has built-in support for handling duplicate form submissions using the "Synchronizer Token Pattern". To get started you define a token on the form tag"

You can read how in: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#formtokens

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I didn't make it clear enough this is using Spring security plugin, which posts eventually into j_spring_security_check so I have no control I can see over that to use withForm ...not that I can yet see anyway.

Comment: When you use Spring Security Plugin, it generate standards views and controllers. You can edit views/login/auth.gsp and controller/.../LoginController.groovy using above information.

Comment: Problem is the form posts to j_spring_security_check so you dont have a controller to work with, I guess there is some way around this but for now my self-answered solution seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Traced the core issue being a User.save() (eg to update last login time) being called in custom UserDetailsService, Hibernate session was closed on the subsequent calls for each user.

Moved the User.save() to AuthenticationEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) and it works fine.  Still would be good to know how to handle duplicate posts to j_spring_security_check